# In-app subscription apps

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, in-app-purchase

Does anyone know of an app that implemented an in-app subscription?

EDIT

====

Just to be clear I'm referring to implementing an in-app purchase of type "subscription" as apple defines it and not implementing a consumable and calling it subscription.

=====

I thought about how the subscription model can be implemented and always ends up with more problems to every possible solution I can think of, so I'm wondering if anyone knows of an app that actually does that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FitnessBuilder (http://www.pumpone.com/fitnessbuilder.html) implements In-App Subscriptions. Let me know if you have specific questions about how the subscription system works.

Comment: Thanks Steven. Are you sure the use the "subscription" in app type? Or do they use the "consumable" type and calling it subscription?

Comment: Yes, we use the subscription type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and you suggestion for further help. It's good to know that someone is using it - it means its doable.  My main issue is how do you assign an account you can track to a purchase so you can let the user use the subscription on more than one device as Apple requires.

Comment: You have to setup a whole user system / server infrastructure to do this properly. So let users sign up with an email address / password, then let them buy something, and then if they login on another device the server would give them rights to whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific app that has implemented in app subscriptions, and that strikes me as being "not a programming question." But Urban Airship offers a hosted in app purchase solution which does have support for subscriptions:

> This might be used to buy a new map
>   pack, game item or subscription based
>   content.

http://urbanairship.com/faq/

I think you will mostly need to implement the exact mechanics of the system yourself. Users will need to "renew" their subscription by making separate in app purchases.

Comment: Thanks for the link to urban airship. I knew they existed but couldn't remember their name.

It is true that it's not just a programming question, but I'm not even sure at the moment that it can be solved programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen MotionXGPS Drive do that... They have a rate of $2.99 a month or $24.99 a year. You still do however, have to renew it manually.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Are you sure the use the "subscription" in app type? Or do they use the "consumable" type and calling it subscription?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's consumable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm main interested in the challenges of implementing a "subscription" type in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect if the product is of the subscription type is to purchase it twice. The second time you do it, you'll see a message that warns you about the nature of the product (subscription) and the kind of purchasing (renew).